# Arrow with multiline expression above and below

Tags: math-mode

I was trying to write this in latex
[image]

but I don't know how to to insert the arrow in the middle with the expressions below and above on it.

Comment: take a look at the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath`) and look at section 4.9, "extensible arrows".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `\substack` together with `\xrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
\xrightarrow
 [% below
  \substack{a+cx+x^2\\s+x}
 ]
 {% above
  \substack{a+cx+x^2\\s+x}
 }
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is plain tex but comes nearer to what you want, if you really want it and not the better aligned version above.

```
$$
{{\atop\qquad}\atop\left(\matrix{
a&b&c\cr
a&b&c\cr
a&b&c\cr
}\right)}
{{x\atop y}\atop\overrightarrow{\matrix{\qquad a\qquad\cr b\cr}}}
{{\atop\qquad}\atop\left(\matrix{
a&b&c\cr
a&b&c\cr
a&b&c\cr
}\right)
}
$$
\vfill\bye
```

[image: plain tex math]